# Angular Injection value alters also the original value (Angular Material Dialog)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I created a popup form to edit values from a table, however once I start modifing the data in the form it instantly changes the original ones in the table as I type even with the Dialog box open.

This is my main component:

```js
import { Version } from './../models/Version';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { ProjectsService } from '../services/projects.service';
import { ClientsService } from '../services/clients.service';
import { VersionsService } from '../services/versions.service';
import { Project } from '../models/Project';
import { EditprojectComponent } from './edit-project/editproject.component';
import {
  MatDialog,
  MatDialogRef,
  MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
  PageEvent,
  MatTableDataSource,
  MatPaginator
} from '@angular/material';
import { Client } from '../models/Client';

interface UIEntries {
  ProjectName: string;
  Client: string;
  Version: string;
  SOW: string;
  PM: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.css']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {
  entries: UIEntries = {
    ProjectName: '',
    Client: '',
    Version: '',
    SOW: '',
    PM: ''
  };

  projects: Project[] = [];
  project: Project = new Project();
  loadingProjects: Boolean = true;
  clients: Client[];
  versions: Version[];

  length;
  pageSize = 5;
  pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 100];

  // MatPaginator Output
  pageEvent: PageEvent;
  dataSource;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Name', 'Client', 'SOW', 'PM', 'Version'];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  setPageSizeOptions(setPageSizeOptionsInput: string) {
    this.pageSizeOptions = setPageSizeOptionsInput.split(',').map(str => +str);
  }

  constructor(
    private _auth: AuthService,
    private _clients: ClientsService,
    private _versions: VersionsService,
    private _projects: ProjectsService,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    this._projects.getProjects().subscribe(res => {
      res.forEach(apiProject => {
        const tempProject = new Project();
        tempProject.populateProject(
          apiProject.Name,
          apiProject.ClientId,
          apiProject.VersionId,
          apiProject.Sow,
          apiProject.Pm,
          apiProject.CreatedBy
        );
        tempProject.ID = apiProject.Id;
        tempProject.Client = apiProject.Client;
        tempProject.Version = apiProject.Version;
        tempProject.Assignments = apiProject.Assignment;
        this.projects.push(tempProject);
      });
      this.length = this.projects.length;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Project>(this.projects);
      console.log(this.projects);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.loadingProjects = false;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._clients.getClients().subscribe(res => {
      this.clients = res;
    });
    this._versions.getProjectVersions().subscribe(res => {
      this.versions = res;
    });
  }

  deleteProject(project: Project) {
    this._projects.deleteProject(project.ID).subscribe(res => {
      this.projects = [];
      this._projects.getProjects().subscribe(response => {
        response.forEach(apiProject => {
          const tempProject = new Project();
          tempProject.populateProject(
            apiProject.name,
            apiProject.clientId,
            apiProject.versionId,
            apiProject.sow,
            apiProject.pm,
            apiProject.createdBy
          );
          tempProject.ID = apiProject.id;
          this.projects.push(tempProject);
        });
        this.loadingProjects = false;
      });
    });
  }

  addProject() {
    this.project.Name = this.entries.ProjectName;
    this.project.VersionID = this.entries.Version;
    this.project.ClientID = this.entries.Client;
    this.project.SOW = this.entries.SOW;
    this.project.PM = this.entries.PM;
    this.project.CreatedBy = this._auth.user.UserID;
    this._projects.insertProject(this.project).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.projects.push(res);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }

  editProject(project: Project) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditprojectComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      height: '450px',
      data: { project: project, clients: this.clients, versions: this.versions }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBody">
  <div class="leftBody">
    <h3>Add new project</h3>
    <div class="addproject-container mat-elevation-z1">
      <form (ngSubmit)="addProject()" class="form-container">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="entries.ProjectName"
            name="ProjectName"
            matInput
            required
            placeholder="Project Name"/>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select
            [(ngModel)]="entries.Client"
            required
            name="Client"
            placeholder="Client">
            <mat-option
              *ngFor="let client of clients; let i = index"
              [value]="client.Name">{{client.Name}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select
            [(ngModel)]="entries.Version"
            name="Version"
            required
            placeholder="Version">
            <mat-option
              *ngFor="let version of versions; let i = index"
              [value]="version.Description"
              >{{version.Description}}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="entries.SOW"
            matInput
            name="SOW"
            required
            placeholder="SOW"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input
            [(ngModel)]="entries.PM"
            matInput
            name="PM"
            required
            placeholder="PM"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
        <div class="button-container">
          <button mat-raised-button>Add Project</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="rightBody">
    <h3>Existing Projects</h3>
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="loadingProjects"></mat-spinner>
    <div class="listproject-container">
      <div *ngIf="!loadingProjects"  class="listproject-scrollcontainer mat-elevation-z1">
        <table  mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
              <button mat-button (click)="editProject(projects[i])">{{element.Name}}</button></td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="Client">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Client</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              {{element.Client.Name}}
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="SOW">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>SOW</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.SOW}}</td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="PM">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>PM</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.PM}}</td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="Version">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Version</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Version.Description}}</td>
          </ng-container>
          <tr
            mat-header-row
            *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"
          ></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <mat-paginator #paginatorPlaceholder
        [length]="length"
        [pageSize]="pageSize"
        [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
        (page)="pageEvent = $event"
      >
      </mat-paginator>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the Dialog PopUp component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from 'src/app/models/Project';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editproject',
  templateUrl: './editproject.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editproject.component.css']
})
export class EditprojectComponent implements OnInit {

  popupProject: Project = new Project();
  clients: any;
  versions: any;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<{EditprojectComponent: any}>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
    this.popupProject = data.project;
    this.clients = data.clients;
    this.versions = data.versions;
    console.log(this.popupProject);
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  submitEdit() {

  }
}
```

```html
<div  mat-dialog-content>
<form (ngSubmit)="submitEdit()" class="form-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input [(ngModel)]="popupProject.Name" name="ProjectName" matInput required placeholder="Project Name">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="popupProject.Client.Name" required name="Client" placeholder="Client">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let client of clients; let i=index" [value]="client.Name">{{client.Name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="popupProject.Version.Description" name="Version" required placeholder="Version">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let version of versions; let i=index" [value]="version.Description">{{version.Description}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input [(ngModel)]="popupProject.SOW" matInput name="SOW" required placeholder="SOW">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input [(ngModel)]="popupProject.PM" matInput name="PM" required placeholder="PM">
  </mat-form-field>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="popupProject" cdkFocusInitial>Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

What i want to achive is to have the form in the popup as just a copy if the table value and only save it once the save button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass objects to the dialog as data, those objects will be accessible and modifiable by the dialog. You've passed to your dialog the project object used in the table, and all of your dialog's fields are bound to that object so changes to those fields act on the original project object. You should be passing in a copy of the project:

```
editProject(project: Project) {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditprojectComponent, {
    width: '400px',
    height: '450px',
    data: { 
      project: {
        Name: project.Name,
        Client: project.Client,
        ...
      }, 
      clients: this.clients, 
      versions: this.versions 
    }
  });
}
```

You will probably need to be more thorough and may need to do a deep copy of the object. It would be simpler and probably safer to pass only the values of the object members that you need in the dialog, rather than the whole project object. This might be a lot easier too.

And then of course when the dialog is 'saved' you will need to update the original project object with the data passed back from the dialog in your dialogRef.afterClosed() handler (which you haven't shown).

Comment: Thanks this really helped ! I didn't thought about sending it that way.
I actually tried to send the project like {...project}, i've read that this actually sends a copy of the object when it's used and not the actually object, but still it didn't work.